# Decoding a base64 / base64url from a url in the browser

Tags: encoding, base64, decoding, base64url

First of all I would like to mention that I have no prior experience with this, so please bare over if the question sounds stupid.

I have a URL that creates some sort of query, but it's encoded as either base64 or base64url. I'm not sure which one of them.

The url itself looks like the following: `https://example.com/req.php?req=0-0S97kzhT60089CUZpOmkXlD7sCrhHI8BJ6fAw2IFucwKe2ggnNAZ9iuaWEoK7ziIRnau3to3KmtrJGBW8ubXIPltFm-W8FTcgriA==&rnd=50000.794176&c=50000`

From my basic web understanding I assume that `&` is a new parameter in the url.

I've tried various base64 / base64url tools online to help me decode it, but have been unsuccessful so far. I assume this is the encoded part? `0-0S97kzhT60089CUZpOmkXlD7sCrhHI8BJ6fAw2IFucwKe2ggnNAZ9iuaWEoK7ziIRnau3to3KmtrJGBW8ubXIPltFm-W8FTcgriA==&rnd=50000.794176&c=50000`

The various tools i've tried returns that it's not UTF-8 or just rubbish text

Can anyone help me with various resources I should look into or share their knowledge.

Comment: Oh okay that's a bummer. Definitely not an image, so I would assume it's encrypted then.

Comment: The part `0-0S97kzhT60089CUZpOmkXlD7sCrhHI8BJ6fAw2IFucwKe2ggnNAZ9iuaWEoK7ziIRnau3to3KmtrJGBW8ubXIPltFm-W8FTcgriA==` is a valid URL safe Base 64 encoded piece. However, decoding it results in binary data with not obvious format.

Comment: @Codo I did some further testing afterwards and I managed to get to know the output is AES encrypted. Thanks for the input !